# How to get started on this statistics problem?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables that are independent also $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on the interval $(0, 1)$.
If $Z=\max \{ X, Y \}$. Then find the probability that $Z \leq z$ and then determine the probability density function of $Z$.

Okay so I must admit I an trumped by this question but I think it's mainly to do with not actually understanding what I'm meant to do. Here are my issues:

1) Okay so $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ does that mean that it is $0$ elsewhere?

2) What exactly is $Z$ is it just the maximum value that either $X$ or $Y$ can take and how exactly do I interpret this? At the moment I'm just thinking of two graphs and $Z$ being the highest point that is taken on both graphs in $X$ or $Y$ since this is a uniform distribution then it will be the same highest point for all values in the interval on either $X$ or $Y$ whatever is highest. This is just intuition again I'm not sure.

3) What is  $P(Z \leq z)$ actually meaning? I'm guessing this is because I'm confused on what $Z$ is and so I can't get this either.

If anyone could help me on this it would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Technically speaking, $P(X=x) = 0 \ \forall x$

Answer (score 0):

1. $X,Y$  are uniformly distribute on $(0,1)$, that mean that their density is $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \notin (0,1)$.
2. Do you know what random variable is?
3. $P(Z \leq z) = P(max\{X,Y\} \leq z) = P(X \leq z \wedge Y \leq z) = P(X \leq z)P(Y \leq z)$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Now can you write a desity function of $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an example with some simulated data will help you visualize what
values of the random variable Z look like.

Five randomly selected values of X (rounded to 2 places for simplicity).

0.95, 0.04, 0.97, 0.16, 0.63.

Similarly, five values of X:

0.16, 0.39, 0.39, 0.38, 0.96.

Now compare the lists. The first value of X is .95 and the first value of Y is .16,
so Z is the larger of the two, which is .95. Similarly for the other
four values. So here are the five values of Z:

0.85, 0.39, 9,87, 0.38, 0.96

Notice that the numbers in Z tend to be larger.

Now, following through the logic of the previous answer,
you will get that the cumulative distribution function of Z
is $P(Z \leq z) = F_Z(z) = z^2,$ for $0 < z < 1$, and $f_Z(z) = 0$ for 
other values of $z$.

Taking the derivative of $F_Z(z)$ with respect to $z$, we get probability density function of Z,
which is 
$f_Z(z) = 2z$, for $0 < z < 1$, and $f_Z(z) = 0$ for other values
of $z$.

If you sketch this density function you will get a triangular shape.
[The corners are at (0,0) (1,0) and (1,2).]
Notice that the curve is highest towards the right side, indicating
that values of Z tend to be larger than 1/2 more often than smaller.

The expected (or mean) values of the original random variables are
E(X) = E(Y) = 1/2. Do you know how to use the density function of Z
to get E(Z) = 2/3? This larger average value goes along with the
concept that values of Z tend to be larger than the values of the
two uniformly distributed random variables X and Y.